# How to choose grid and block size when processing huge image

Tags: c++, performance, cuda

I want to label a really big image using CUDA. The binary image is 48000*2048.

I set block 64*16 and grid 750*128. My device is GTX950m.

but it works slow.

the kernel:

```
__global__ void labelCUDA(const PtrStepSz<uint8_t> src, PtrStepSz<int> label)
{
    int width = src.cols;
    int height = src.rows;
    int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int L = x + y * width;

    if (x >= width || y >= height) return;

    if (src(y, x) != 0)
        label(y, x) = L;
    else
        label(y, x) = 0;
}
```

the caller:

```
...
    dim3 blockDim(64, 16);
    dim3 gridDim(750, 128);

    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord(start);

    labelCUDA << <gridDim, blockDim>> > (src, label);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cudaEventElapsedTime(gpuTime, start, stop);
    cout << "Gpu used " << *gpuTime << " ms.\n";
...
```

It turns out to spend 578.101ms.
Is there anything wrong with my configuration? Or I need to split the image into several smaller pieces to handle?

Comment: Juts.. try different ones! Likely making each thread compute more than 1 value will accelerate your code, but often you just need to try different values to see what works best. You can also profile it and get performance figures to know what is the bottleneck.  It also depends how your image is stored in memory which affects how fast you can read from it. If you want 2D block, you better store the image in some way that exploits 2D structures of the images (like textures). Otherwise an image its just a 1D array in general, so perhaps better to  launch 1D kernels.

Comment: Unless there is more code that you haven't shown in between your `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` and your `cudaEventElapsedTime()`, your timing methodology is broken.  You are supposed to record the `stop` event and also synchronize on the `stop` event.  When I fix those problems, your code runs in 6.6 milliseconds on my GTX960.  A GTX950m will be slower than a GTX960, but it will not be 2 orders of magnitude slower.  I note that you appear to be running on windows.  Make sure you are building a Release project and not a Debug project.

Comment: according to my testing, you can get an additional 5% speedup (so, 0.3ms improvement in my test case) by refactoring your kernel code like this: `int res = 0;    if (src(y, x) != 0)  res = L;
        label(y, x) = res;`  I would normally suggest leaving such trivialities to the compiler, but I pass it along as a factoid which may be of interest.  CUDA 10.1.105

Comment: @RobertCrovella Release mode is the point! The code operates in 23ms now. That's amazing! Thanks a lot!